# Where is scss file located in extjs application

Tags: extjs, sass, styles, cls

I've been trying to figure out styling in extjs, but I cannot find where appropriate styles are located.
For example, in admin dashboard application the style of textfield is defined as:

```
xtype: 'textfield',
cls: 'auth-textbox',
```

but, I've been searching for appearance of text 'auth-textbox' in all files in the whole workspace, and there is no such definition. In addition, if I comment the line containing cls, nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this class is not defined.  This class is simply added to the widgets element.  It does not necessarily need to be defined and of course in that case it will do nothing.

If you have a Extjs class definition (not css class) called App.view.MyClass.js  This file should be in your application directory in view/MyClass.js  and you can create a scss file called view/MyClass.scss and sencha command will process this file. The default app.json tells sencha command to look for this file.

You can look at your compiled scss files in your build folder under development/{YOURAPPNAME}/resources.  The files will be {YOURAPPNAME}-all_[1234...etc].css  If you define a class then it should be in these files and it will tell you what file it was defined in.

```
/* /u/xxx/work/temp/dcs3/webapp/erp/ws/packages/local/dcs/src/Dcs/view/util/ColoredCircleAvatar.scss:29 */
.circleavatar > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```